# hibernate join table mysql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, join

I have two simple tables.

```
    mysql> select * from filesshare;
+----+--------+--------+-------+
| id | userId | fileId | owner |
+----+--------+--------+-------+
|  1 |      2 |      1 |     1 |
|  2 |      3 |      1 |     1 |
|  3 |      4 |      2 |     1 |
|  4 |      5 |      2 |     1 |
+----+--------+--------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from filesinfo;
+----+-----------------+-----------------------------------+
| id | name            | url                               |
+----+-----------------+-----------------------------------+
|  1 | dwnld_btn.png   | C:\shareapp\admin\dwnld_btn.png   |
|  2 | dwnld_btn_1.png | C:\shareapp\admin\dwnld_btn_1.png |
+----+-----------------+-----------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

i will have now two values as input. 1) userId 2) owner

now assume userId=3 and owner=1. Now i want out put to match all the rows with given values in filesshare table in this case its second row that is " 2 | 3 | 1 | 1 " now i want that column three value which is 1 now. Then with that value i want to retrieve the data from filesinfo table. in this case the first row of filesinfo table will b the output. like this:

```
+----+-----------------+-----------------------------------+
| id | name            | url                               |
+----+-----------------+-----------------------------------+
|  1 | dwnld_btn.png   | C:\shareapp\admin\dwnld_btn.png   |
+----+-----------------+-----------------------------------+
```

is that possible using joins using hibernate, a simple example can be a kickstart for me.

**i tried this**

```
mysql> Select fileid,name,url from filesshare fs,filesinfo fi where fs.fileid=fi
.id;
+--------+-----------------+-----------------------------------+
| fileid | name            | url                               |
+--------+-----------------+-----------------------------------+
|      1 | dwnld_btn.png   | C:\shareapp\admin\dwnld_btn.png   |
|      1 | dwnld_btn.png   | C:\shareapp\admin\dwnld_btn.png   |
|      1 | dwnld_btn.png   | C:\shareapp\admin\dwnld_btn.png   |
|      1 | dwnld_btn.png   | C:\shareapp\admin\dwnld_btn.png   |
|      2 | dwnld_btn_1.png | C:\shareapp\admin\dwnld_btn_1.png |
|      2 | dwnld_btn_1.png | C:\shareapp\admin\dwnld_btn_1.png |
|      2 | dwnld_btn_1.png | C:\shareapp\admin\dwnld_btn_1.png |
|      2 | dwnld_btn_1.png | C:\shareapp\admin\dwnld_btn_1.png |
+--------+-----------------+-----------------------------------+
```

Thanks and regards

Comment: Is it neccessary to define -@onetomany and  -@joincolumn in the entity class to use joins in hql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in hibernate you can deal with it two ways:

- use plain sql

  example:
          SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("select fi.* from fileshare fs, filesinfo fi where fs.fileId =fi.id and fs. userId = :uid and fs.owner = :oid");
          query.setInteger("uid", userid);
          query.setInteger("oid", ownerid);

  ```
     /*maybe deal with transformation */
     query.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);)
     return  (List<Map<String,Object>>)query.list();
  ```

  here is the link with info on transformation details: 
  http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-associations
- use hql assuming you have entities mapped to

  example:

  ```
    Criteria crit =  session.createCriteria(Filesinfo.class)
    crit.setFetchMode("fs.fileshare", FetchMode.JOIN);
    crit.add( Restrictions.eq("fs.userId", userid) Restrictions.eq("fs.owner", ownerid) );
    return crit.list();

  all info on this method is here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html

   and here is the details of teh ORM mapping via xml: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/xml.html
  ```

Comment: how to map entities in this case? please let me kno

Comment: Is it neccessary to define -@onetomany and -@joincolumn in the entity class to use joins in hql? @Max Dron

Answer (score 0):

Select id,name,url from fileshare fs,filesinfo fi where fs.id=fs.id;

Comment: hi. i edited the question once have a look, i tried with similar query. and output also there

Comment: why are you using id column? plz provide little description, to make clear the question.

Comment: is that possible using single query like join ?

Comment: inner jopin will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

k guys this one one after scratching head, of course help from google also.

```
     mysql> select a.id, a.name, a.url from filesinfo a inner join filesshare b on 
a.id=b.fileid where b.userid=5 and b.owner=1;
    +----+-----------------+-----------------------------------+
    | id | name            | url                               |
    +----+-----------------+-----------------------------------+
    |  2 | dwnld_btn_1.png | C:\shareapp\admin\dwnld_btn_1.png |
    |  4 | loader3.gif     | C:\shareapp\admin\loader3.gif     |
    +----+-----------------+-----------------------------------+
    2 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: how to do the same with hibernate annotations